# What storage should I use for a outlook plugin?

Tags: plugins, outlook, vsto, storage

What storage system should I use , If i'm going to deploy a outlook plugin with VSTO ?

Is it possible to use outlook's , which is for email ?

**UPDATE**

I thought about SQL Express , but I  think I should use the same thing with what outlook uses , that would save troubles

Comment: What do you want to put into storage? User settings? Do they need to be global/roaming or machine-specific?

Comment: @SliverNinja data that's better stored in database , like special information related to contacts , I thought about SQL Express , but I  think I should use the same thing with what outlook uses , that would save troubles

Comment: What will be the consumer of the persisted data - only your Outlook plugin or do other clients need to interface with it?

Comment: @SliverNinja no , as long as I can handle the data within the outlook plugin , it's all good ; besides , I can write an exporter for it

Comment: @warl0ck Hi, which approach among those mentioned in the anser was more suitable for you? I am trying to achieve something on the similar lines.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are numerous options for you to consider, below I've listed all the ones I've seen used in the past.

1. For Outlook-managed storage you could look into using [`StorageItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.storageitem.aspx) which is a hidden item inside a given folder (*Inbox, etc.*). Using the `StorageItem` you can add [custom user properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.userproperties.add.aspx) and file attachments.
2. You can also create new Folder and mark it as hidden using the [`PR_ATTR_HIDDEN` flag](http://books.google.com/books?id=JG_6oJyVCsYC&pg=PT1079&lpg=PT1079&dq=outlook%20PR_ATTR_HIDDEN&source=bl&ots=kYMRGryBaQ&sig=-7y-cVzl2Ma5qf6FNewJ9j3GQnM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7BqMT9f3KInI0QGJyvT5CQ&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=outlook%20PR_ATTR_HIDDEN&f=false). Adding any mail items or journal items would only be visible to your add-in since you can access hidden folders via the API - but not via Outlook interface.
3. I've also seen users store information inside Outlook journal items serialized as XML (*as is done by [jello-dashboard](http://jello-dashboard.net/)*).
4. You could [create a custom store via `AddStore`](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/03/19/outlook-personal-folders-store/) to construct a local PST.
5. Alternately, you could store data external to the Outlook system for consumption by your addin. External stores could be [local Environment paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10035529/175679), local/remote databases, or web service calls.

Comment: @SilverNinja is There a way to show the StorageItem inside of the folder? It seems like I cant see it. Which file type does the hidden item have?