# Getting RDOMail for MailItem opened from .msg file

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2003, outlook-redemption

Is there a way of creating an [`RDOMail`](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) instance for a [`MailItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210946%28v=office.11%29.aspx) corresponding to an Outlook message opened from a `.msg` file?

My usual approach is to get the [`CurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211820%28v=office.11%29.aspx) from the `Inspector`, cast it to `MailItem`, retrieve its `EntryID` and `StoreID` values, and finally load it from an [`RDOSession`](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) through the `GetMessageFromID` method.

However, in the case of messages opened from a `.msg`, the `EntryID` property returns `null`. Is there another way around this? I assume I could use the `GetMessageFromMsgFile` method instead, but how do I retrieve the full path of the message from the `MailItem`?

P.S. The solution should ideally work with the Outlook 2003 object model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do two approaches here...

1. Save the `MailItem` to disk using [`_MailItem.SaveAs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.saveas.aspx). Then use `GetMessageFromMsgFile`.
2. Save the `MailItem` to a `Folder` (store) to persist it, giving it an `EntryID` and `StoreID`. Use [`MailItem.Save()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866979.aspx) and [`MailItem.Move(tempFolder)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268996%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to persist the MSG to a folder. I typically use a [hidden folder for this storage swap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10175091/175679). You would need to periodically purge this swap folder on startup or at regular intervals (*Outlook has lingering locks, so you better use try/catches*).

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for something more lightweight (performance-wise) that didn't involve saving, since this operation needs to be performed on the UI thread, but I think I'll go with your second approach.