# How to share user roaming settings between two different Office JS Add-ins?

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

In other words, can add-in A read the roaming settings of add-in B?

Answer (score 1):

The [RoamingSettings API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_7/office.roamingsettings?view=office-js) only returns settings stored by the add-in that calls it.

If you are developing both add-ins, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536439/where-to-store-larger-data-for-outlook-web-app) for ideas on where to store information outside of roaming settings.